# How can I move data from one model to another with Django/python?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

---

basically, I have three models where the information of the user is already there, but I created a third model called `UserLicense` so that I can move the information to that model, how can I do that in an efficient way?

Model 1

```py
class License1(models.Model):
    full_name = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    email = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    expire_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False)
    unitcode = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    wg_version = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, null=False)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Model 2

```py
class License2(models.Model):
    full_name = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    email = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    expire_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False)
    unitcode = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    wg_version = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, null=False)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

User Model

```py
class UserLicense(models.Model):
    """User information model."""
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    email = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
```

I'm using `db.sqlite3`, if anyone can explain the process I would be really grateful.

Comment: The `UserLicense` looks quite suspiciously what is already stored in the `User` model...

Comment: The user model is empty, i have to fill it up with the full_name, user_name and email of the other two models

Comment: Do you want to move the data of tables `License1` and `License2` into the `UserLicense` table?

Comment: Yes basically, License1 and License2 already have users, so i want to move all those user to UserLicense which is empty and after that create a foreign key, but i don't know how to move that data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move the information from `License1` and `License2` to `UserLicense`, I suggest a simple management command that can write a script that loops through all the instances of both `License1` and `License2`, creates a new instance of `UserLicense` for each one, and copies over the relevant information. Here's an example of how you can do it:

```py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from myapp.models import License1, License2, UserLicense

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Migrates data from License1 and License2 to UserLicense'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        license1_objects = License1.objects.all()
        license2_objects = License2.objects.all()

        # Move the data from the License1 table
        for license1 in license1_objects:
            UserLicense.objects.create(
                user_name=license1.user_name,
                full_name=license1.full_name,
                email=license1.email,
            )
        
        # Move the data from the License2 table
        for license2 in license2_objects:
            UserLicense.objects.create(
                user_name=license2.user_name,
                full_name=license2.full_name,
                email=license2.email,
            )
        license1_objects.delete()
        license2_objects.delete()


        self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('Data migration complete.'))
```

To make the above script a Django management command, you should paste it in a .py module for example `migrate_data.py` in the `management` directory, and in it, another directory called `commands` in your app's directory; So after this change, your app structure looks like below pattern:

```
app/
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    models.py
    management/
        __init__.py
        commands/
            __init__.py
            migrate_data.py
    tests.py
    views.py
```

With the above script, you can move data just one time running this command using `python manage.py migrate_data` in your Django server.

Comment: you're welcome and good luck to you Angel 

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to sync `UserLicense` with other two models and you are still maintaining other two models then you can use management command but if you only need to load them once and discard or archive other two models then you can just run the commands in a shell no need for management command.

Morever the solution @Javad has presented is not efficient as it is iterating over each instance and saving them indivially causing more database hits.

The efficient solution is to do bulk query like this:

```
licenses1 = [UserLicense(user_name=l.user_name, full_name=l.full_name, email=l.email) for l in License1.objects.all()]
UserLicense.objects.bulk_create(licenses1)

licenses2 = [UserLicense(user_name=l.user_name, full_name=l.full_name, email=l.email) for l in License2.objects.all()]
UserLicense.objects.bulk_create(licenses2)
```